# Building xcframework does not include package dependencies

Tags: swift, xcode, build, xcframework

I have a simple swift package which depends on another open-source package.
Everything works as expected on my local machine. I'm able to add my swift package into a ios application and it runs properly (including the dependant package).

When I try to build the package as binary (xcframework) the build completes with no errors, but when I integrate my package I get error "No such module <dependant_package>". What is the proper way to incorporate the 3rd party package into the final binary?

Here is the Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13) // Specify the desired iOS version
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/example/dependant.git", branch: "master")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "dependant", package: "dependant")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```